# Why was Reagan sworn in twice for his second term?

Tags: united-states, president, 1980s, ceremony

I was looking at [Wikipedia's article on Justice Potter Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Potter_Stewart&oldid=951914452) and was surprised to read:

> On January 20 and 21, 1985, Stewart administered the oath of office for Vice President George H. W. Bush.

(He was Reagan's vice president.) Likewise [the Wikipedia article on that inauguration](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Second_inauguration_of_Ronald_Reagan&oldid=972545727) begins:

> The second inauguration of Ronald Reagan as President of the United States was held in a small televised ceremony on Sunday, January 20, 1985, at the Grand Foyer of the White House, and was to be repeated the following day, January 21, 1985 at the West Front of the United States Capitol in Washington, D.C., before being moved to the Capitol's rotunda.

It does not, however, explain *why* there were two oaths administered. [Wikipedia's article on the oath of office](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Oath_of_office_of_the_President_of_the_United_States&oldid=971732799#List_of_swearing-in_events) also lists dual swearings-in for Reagan's second term, as well as for a few other presidential terms, but doesn't give a reason.

I'm particularly curious about Reagan's, because the article quoted above indicates that the first ceremony was "televised" so (a) there's seemingly no point in the second ceremony since everyone there had seen it already and (b) the second ceremony seemingly would be absurd since everyone there would know it was a sham. So **why was Reagan sworn in twice for his second term as president**?

Note that I'm not asking why there were two celebrations — people like to celebrate. I'm asking why *the oath itself* was administered twice.

Comment: [Weather](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/why-is-obama-being-sworn-in-twice/) and public expectations; you can't have a parade for a televised event. (Macy's notwithstanding).

Comment: Note that Obama was given the oath twice by Justice Roberts in 2008, because they screwed up the first one.

Comment: If weather were the reason, they would have delayed that second oath even longer in 1985.  I seem to recall it barely made it above 0 F in Washington that day.

Comment: @T.E.D. NB - it was 2009 when Roberts administered the oath of office, not 2008.

Comment: @T.E.D. I almost just asked *Obama, Roberts, oath; how did the two very articulate orators mess it up? I have never understood what exactly happened when...* but then decided it's not a good fit here. I want to know if Roberts simply made a brain freeze mistake (which is hard for me to believe based on watching Roberts talk) or if it was something else, but I don't know if there's a viable SE question here (or in History SE), or not. Any thoughts?

Comment: @uhoh - I was watching it live, and IMHO Roberts seemed super nervous. He had never done anything like this before, and likely 10's of millions were watching live. A lot of people forget politicians are still human beings, not self-serving robots. When *he* messed up, it threw off Obama. This kind of thing happens in plays too when a line gets messed up, the weirdity can cascade until everyone manages to find their way back on script. There's probably an interview somewhere where Roberts talks about it in detail though.

Comment: @T.E.D. thanks! I should give it a watch. I think of jurists as different than politicians, but certainly the swearing in of a president for the first time isn't something one practices in law school :-)

Comment: @CMonsour, you are quite right.  I was scheduled to march in the inauguration parade and was very, very happy that it was cancelled.  Incredibly cold with a very chill wind.

Answer (score 27):

You will see from the [Oath of office WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_office_of_the_President_of_the_United_States) that this pattern of two inaugurations always has the first ceremony labeled as "private". The POTUS has to be sworn in on the first day of office.

But having a *public* ceremony where people could actually *attend* (instead of watching on TV), where parades could be held and such, is not always possible on that first day. In recent times, this was usually because that first day of office fell on a Sunday.

[WhiteHouseHistory](https://www.whitehousehistory.org/reagans-second-inauguration) says as much (the first oath being private because it fell on a Sunday).

---

Other entries -- Chester A. Arthur, Calvin Coolidge -- point towards the new POTUS not being in Washington for the first oath, which is also a good reason to have a second ceremony in the capitol a couple of days later.

Comment: So the public one is effectively just for show I guess. As the private one will have officially sworn in the president.

Comment: Personally, I don't consider repeating an oath to be a "sham". Certain people put a lot of weight on those; some on the fact who is administering it, others that it be taken in public, some that it be taken in a certain location and so on. So to each his/her own, I'd say.

Comment: Me neither, as long as it doesn't cancel out the initial one, which this doesn't.

Comment: DevSolar, thanks. As I said at the end of my question post, "I'm not asking why there were two celebrations — people like to celebrate. I'm asking why _the oath itself_ was administered twice". Do you think your answer could address that more specifically?

Comment: @msh210: I think that much is a bit opinion-based. I commented on that; for you, taking the oath again is a "sham". For me, it's to satisfy a different requirement. The first is because without the oath, there's no POTUS. The second is, because people want to *witness* the ceremony. You see the second oath in a negative light, I don't. So the answer to your comment -- why was it administered twice -- would be, "why not?".

Comment: I don't see how asking the motivation of a particular group of people in 1985 is opinion-based. I mean, it's based on _their_ opinions, of course, but that might be a matter of public record.

Comment: @msh210: The motivation is, basically, "*because that is how it's always been done*". Look at that list of oaths you linked. The only ones that were *only* private (without a second, public oath being held) were those when a presiding POTUS had died (Harrison, Lincoln, McKinley, Harding, Roosevelt, Kennedy). Reagan was by no means the first or only one to take two oaths (Hayes, Arthur, Wilson, Coolidge, Eisenhower, Obama). Yours is basically a no-question; do you have any sources that someone other than you thinks this to be out of the ordinary?

Comment: (re your comment) It's hard to compare Reagan's swearing-in with most that preceded him, since his so-called "private" one was actually broadcast nationally and thus was not private at all. But that's beside the point that my question sought the motivations for the dual swearing-in, which is a valid question even if every single other presidential swearing-in was also dual. If your answer is actually "because that is how it's always been done" then that should be in your answer post, preferably with explanation and providing evidence that that was in fact the motivation.

Comment: @msh210: I still hold that it is *your* opinion that televising the first oath changes anything.

Comment: People go to church on big wedding anniversaries (25y, 50y, so on) and renew their wedding vows publicly.  Why can't a President give his oath twice? Or why couldn't any oath be repeated on any occasion where it makes sense? It's better than forgetting it :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does "the first day of office being on a Sunday" make it *harder* for people to attend?  I'd have thought it would make it easier - no need to try to negotiate time off work!

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Some Christian thing perhaps? I don't know either, it's what the WhiteHouseHistory site stated.

Comment: Taking an oath twice doesn't negate anything. It lets more people witness it and hold you to it. The oath doesn't grant power. It constrains it. US Military people take the same oath of allegiance to the constitution all over again when they're promoted in rank.

Answer (score 16):

The 20th amendment says "The terms of the President and Vice President shall end at noon on the 20th day of January ... and the terms of their successors shall then begin".  The body of the constitution (article II, section I) says: "Before he enter on the Execution of his Office, he shall take the following Oath or Affirmation: *[the oath]*".

As a result, the president always takes the oath right around noon on January 20th.  But, throwing a big inauguration shindig at noon on a Sunday isn't considered appropriate -- it pulls people away from church.  So, when January 20th falls on a Sunday, the incoming president takes the oath in private at noon.  The ceremony is repeated the next day in order to satisfy the need for *pomp and circumstance*.

Comment: "The President must ***always***" Not necessarily. The President doesn't need to take the oath right around noon on January 20th. There is only the need to take it before he or she performs any duties in their official capacity as President. And even that is debatable since the 20th states (after your quoted section ends) that the President-elect's term starts at noon on the 20th day of January. It has not been determined by SCOTUS (because the question has been been raised in court) whether the Oath of Office must be taken before you can do POTUS stuff since the 20th Amendment was ratified.

Comment: @TylerH.  I've updated my answer slightly based on your comments.  Thanks